# Does flutter allow scrolling screenshot functionality?

Tags: flutter, scroll, screenshot

I wanted to know if I am able to make my app using Flutter and still have the functionality of scrolling screenshots.

I have tried to look at other blogs and sites whether they allow this functionality but did not find one.

Comment: what do you mean by scrolling screenshots ?

Comment: I think you can look for taking image from widget

Comment: you mean when you scrennshot the app screen you can click on scroll option then the screenshot will expand to the bottom of the screen?

Comment: @WaliKhan It is a feature on android that allows you to take screenshots of an entire page or a scope you want, and I wanted to know if flutter apps allow you to apply that feature.